# Почему задаётся словарь, а на выходе получается список?

Tags: python-3.x

Имеется такая проблема, что мне нужно написать функцию которая при определённых значениях выдаёт название месяца. **Проблема заключается в следующем**:
я создаю словарь, но словарь получается слишком длинный чтобы записать его в одну строку, так что приходится добавлять значения в этот словарь. Когда я добавляю значения, вместо словаря получается список. Как так получается, и что с этим делать?

```
def month_name(num, lang):
    month_RU = {1: 'январь', 2: 'февраль', 3: 'март', 4: 'апрель', 5: 'май', 6: 'июнь', 7: 'июль'}
    month_RU[8] = ['август']
    month_RU[9] = ['сентябрь']
    month_RU[10] = ['октябрь']
    month_RU[11] = ['ноябрь']
    month_RU[12] = ['декабрь']

    month_ENG = {1: 'january', 2: 'february', 3: 'march', 4: 'april', 5: 'may', 6: 'june', 7: 'july'}
    month_ENG[8] = ['august']
    month_ENG[9] = ['september']
    month_ENG[10] = ['october']
    month_ENG[11] = ['november']
    month_ENG[12] = ['december']

    if lang == 'ru':    
        return month_RU[num].replace('[', '').replace(']', '')   
    elif lang == 'en':
        return month_ENG[num].replace('[', '').replace(']', '')

print(month_name(8, "ru"))
```

Comment: Словарь, как и список, можно спокойно записывать в несколько строк.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы значениям словаря присваиваете список с одной строкой. `month_RU[8] = ['август']` исправьте на `month_RU[8] = 'август'`.

Answer (score 2):

```
def month_name(num, lang):
    month_RU = {
                 1: 'январь', 
                 2: 'февраль', 
                 3: 'март', 
                 4: 'апрель', 
                 5: 'май', 
                 6: 'июнь', 
                 7: 'июль',
                 8: 'август',
                 9: 'сентябрь',
                10: 'октябрь',
                11: 'ноябрь',
                12: 'декабрь'
               }

    month_ENG ={
                 1: 'january', 
                 2: 'february', 
                 3: 'march', 
                 4: 'april', 
                 5: 'may', 
                 6: 'june', 
                 7: 'july',
                 8: 'august',
                 9: 'september',
                10: 'october',
                11: 'november',
                12: 'december'                 
               }

    if lang == 'ru':    
        return month_RU[num]
    elif lang == 'en':
        return month_ENG[num]

print(month_name(8, "ru"))
август
print(month_name(8, "en"))
august
print(month_name(8, "fr"))
None
```